# Is it possible to bold dates in a WPF Calendar Control?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, calendar

I need to mark certain dates in a WPF Calendar control, by making the date bold or changing the background color or something like that.

It would also work if I could customize how blackout dates are rendered (i.e. not crossed out as default, but with another background color etc.)

Is this possible to achieve either of those options?